# Why won't Minecraft open?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Minecraft keeps crashing I cant even open it. I tried many solutions such as reinstalling java and updating my drivers, but no luck. Any ideas?

This is the crash report:

```
[19:06:14 INFO]: Half command: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\javaw.exe -Xmx1G 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M - 
XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump - 
Djava.library.path=
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.13.2\
1.13.2-natives-98659883424300 -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=
java-minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=unknown -cp 

C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.25.Final\netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\brigadier\1.0.14\brigadier-1.0.14.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\datafixerupper\1.0.19\datafixerupper-1.0.19.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.25\authlib-1.5.25.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\8.2.1\fastutil-8.2.1.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.13.9\realms-1.13.9.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\3.1.6\lwjgl-3.1.6.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-jemalloc\3.1.6\lwjgl-jemalloc-3.1.6.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-openal\3.1.6\lwjgl-openal-3.1.6.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-opengl\3.1.6\lwjgl-opengl-3.1.6.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-glfw\3.1.6\lwjgl-glfw-3.1.6.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-stb\3.1.6\lwjgl-stb-3.1.6.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\text2speech-1.10.3.jar;
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.13.2\1.13.2.jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main

[19:06:14 SEVERE]: 
Couldn't launch game
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\javaw.exe" 
(in directory "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft"): 
CreateProcess error=2, Impossibile trovare file specificato
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.mojang.launcher.game.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.game.a.launchGame(Unknown Source)
    at com.mojang.launcher.game.runner.AbstractGameRunner.onDownloadJobFinished(Unknown Source)
    at com.mojang.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.mojang.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
    at com.mojang.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Impossibile trovare il file specificato
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more

[19:06:14 INFO]: Deleting 
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.13.2\1.13.2-natives-98659883424300
```

Comment: Seems like it can't find the Java executable. This is weird, reinstalling Java would be exactly what I would suggest in that case, but you already did that. Can you maybe enter `echo %PATH%` in a terminal and paste the output here?

Comment: Did you install Java without the necessary administrator rights? Or try running the launcher with them?

Answer (score -1):

I hate to say it but you might have to reinstall Minecraft.